# Difference between 'can' and 'could'

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

**Could/can** any native english speaker tell me what the difference between ***'can'*** and ***'could'*** in the following sentences is. And, are they interchangeable in the following context? What Difference do the words ***can*** and ***could*** create when making a request or an offer?

Here are the examples:

- Suppose, I am looking for a particular bank but I don't know where the bank is. I meet an old man and want to know the direction of the bank from him. So I ask him "***Can/Could*** you please tell me where the bank is?"
- ***Can/Could*** anyone please teach me how to share videos and photos on Facebook?

As usual, if there is anything ungrammatical in the writing, please correct it.

Comment: "Could" is more polite than "can".  That's about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your examples **can** and **could** are used to  ask a question.  They also function to make your request sound more polite.

if you just say **Tell me where the bank is.** then this becomes a demand.

As Andrew says **could** sounds a little softer.

In your second sentence you can use either **can** or **could** to make a request (asking someone to help you with Facebook) However, it is also asking someone if they have the **ability** to teach you how to use Facebook, etc.